# flipping a picture over into another image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, flip

im trying to make an image have a flipping animation when hovered over with the mouse.
kind of like a wheel of fortune card flips except its one image on one side and a different version of the image on the other side. any ideas how i do this ?

```
<img src="image1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='image2'" onmouseout="this.src='image1'" />
```

i was looking it up online and i see how to make images rotate but not to flip over into another image. any ideas how to get me started would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think your code should work. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: See this fiddle, it shows your code is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Yk2vX/

Comment: my code works in that it just changes the images. i want it to have a flipping animation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [this article](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/web_graphics/article.php/3479941).

Essentially, what you would want to do is have the two images as separate image objects

```
<img src="image1.jpg"/>
<img src="image2.jpg"/>
```

something to toggle in (in the article's case, an anchor)

```
<a href="index.html" onMouseOver="SwapOut()" onMouseOut="SwapBack()">
```

and finally something to store it (another image)

```
<img name="flippr" src="image1.jpg"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this resource outlines the effect you're trying to achieve. Pretty strong explaination. http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy/